# Taking mouse input curses

Tags: python, python-curses

Can anyone tell me how to take mouse input în Python curses?
And if there is any way that I can create a custom cursor for the mouse inside the terminal when I run the program?

```
curses.set_curs_char('*')
```

Or something in this manner.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look with following code

```
begin_x = 20 ; begin_y = 7
height = 5 ; width = 40
win = curses.newwin(height, width, begin_y, begin_x)
```

For more : https://docspy3zh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/curses.html